# How to prevent last period in captions from appearing in the list of figures?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, captions, punctuation

Is there any simple way of removing the last character of an argument to a command (or environment)? I'm looking for a simple way to remove the punctuation mark from a caption when it appears in the contents list without having to write the same caption twice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using the `caption` package, you can use the option `textformat=period` which will add a period to the caption itself but not to the list entry, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textformat=period]{caption}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{\(\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv1\)}
  \caption{An identity}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Changed to using this instead as I ran into problems with an unwanted space being introduced to the `\captionperiod` command.

Answer (score 12):

The safest way, in my opinion, is to use a command for the final period:

```
...
\DeclareRobustCommand{\captionperiod}{.}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\captionperiod}{}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
... % other lists
\endgroup
...
\begin{figure}
...
\caption{A caption\captionperiod}
\end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

In this way you have a precise control on what you type.

Comment: That's freaking genius! Never thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: Hm, doesn't appear to be working when I'm specifying the caption as argument to a wrapper environment, probably due to expansion. Nope, it's not even working when specified directly into `caption`.

Comment: I made a mistake; check the edited message.

Comment: I also made a mistake and didn't use the `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` but tried `\renewcommand{\captionperiod}{}` ... `\renewcommand{\captionperiod}{.}`. But _now_ it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Ideal task for luatex

```
\def\removelast#1{\directlua{tex.print((string.gsub([==[#1]==], ".$", "")))}}

\removelast{What punctuation?}

\bye
```

You can easily make it more robust and remove the last character only if it is a punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to patch `\@caption`, using tools provided by the `etoolbox` and `xstring` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{%
  \ignorespaces#2%
}{%
  \protecting{\noexpandarg\StrGobbleRight}{\ignorespaces#2}{1}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{\(\sin^2x+\cos^2x\equiv1\)}
  \caption{A \emph{very important} identity!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Note that you must patch `\@memold@caption` instead of `\@caption` if you use the `memoir` document class *without* the `hyperref` package. Furthermore, the patch might have to be adapted if the `caption` package were used. However, as follows from the answer and the comment of Axel Sommerfeldt, a patch is actually not needed in this case since the `caption` package allows to configure the format of the caption text anyway.

Comment: When using the `caption` package the best thing would be defining an own text format with `\DeclareCaptionTextFormat`.

Comment: @mhp, could you please clarify (if possible) how to make your solution work together with ```capton``` package? All my subfigures are now visible in the LOF too :–)